# Swift 4: Errors When Loading Web Page Content in iOS app

Tags: load, swift4, html

The app I'm creating in Xcode 9 needs to load web page content, so I followed the code suggested in [How to load a string from a website URL](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/strings/how-to-load-a-string-from-a-website-url)

```
    if let url = URL(string: "https://flightplanning.navcanada.ca/cgi-bin/Fore-obs/notam.cgi?ni_FIR=on&Stations=CZEG") {
    do {
        let contents = try String(contentsOf: url)
        print(contents)
    } catch {
        // contents could not be loaded
    }
} else {
    // the URL was bad!
}
```

From various other threads, it seemed to be a problem with the info.plist file, so following these suggestions I added the following entries in the info.plist:
[info.plist added entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYuv4.png)

Which looks like this inside the info.plist file:

```
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <false/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>flightplanning.navcanada.ca</key>
        <dict/>
        <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

The errors returned:

```
SSL_ERROR_SSL(1): operation failed within the library
SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/boringssl_Sim/boringssl-109.50.14/ssl/tls_record.c:547:SSL alert number 40
HANDSHAKE_FAILURE_ON_CLIENT_HELLO
Function boringssl_context_get_os_status: line 4268 SSL_AD_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE
TIC TCP Conn Failed
NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9824)
Task <AB92C36B-6E8A-42E5-9C3E-73AF6E258F43>.<0> HTTP load failed (error code: -1200 [3:-9824])
NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1200
```

Any corrective suggestions would be greatly appreciated.